# Where does VLC store Keyboard hotkeys?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I just made an arduino sketch that listens for a physical foot pedal switch button that will send via  serial port a string to a python script that thanks to pyautogui will emulate a keyboard keys press.

Python will then simulate a key press, which is the same of a vlc hotkey binding I use to play/pause a video.

In this way I can play/pause a vlc video by presing the pedal switch.
I hardcoded this keyboard binding in the python script.

Now, just for fun I want to change the hotkeys combination in vlc **and** I would like that python could read this change in a VLC preference file configuration, so that I don't have to manually change every time the script, but I don't know where VLC saves these keyboards global hotkeys.
I am on windows, but I am a regular Linux user... and in linux everything is a file!! 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file that gets updated when VLC hotkeys are changed is file:

`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\vlc\vlcrc`

I note that by default all entries are commented out with `#` prefix to the line.
When a key is changed from the default, the matching entry is uncommented.

This means that the defaults are built-in to VLC, and only changes to the defaults
are noted in the file.

Comment: I previously opened that file but can't find anything...
Now after reading the answer I reopened, with more willing and found

# Play/Pause (string)
global-key-play-pause=Shift+Space

what I needed! thanks